# convert cv2.umat to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, pytorch

Processed_image() function returns a cv2.Umat type value which is to be reshaped from 
3 dimensions`(h, ch, w)` to 4 dimensions`(h, ch, w, 1)` so `i` need it to be converted 
to numpy array or also if possible help me to directally rehshape `cv2.umat` 
type variable to be directally reshaped and converted to a pytorch tensor and can be 
assigned to reshaped_image_tensor.

```
img_w=640
img_h=640
img_ch=3
umat_img = cv2.UMat(img)
display_one(umat_img, "RESPONSE")    #function created by me to display image
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
with torch.no_grad():
    processed_img = preprocess_image(umat_img, model_image_size = (img_h, img_ch, img_w))
    #___________write YOUR CODE here________
    reshaped_images_tensor = torch.from_numpy(processed_img.reshape(img_h, img_ch, img_w, 1)).float().to(device)      #images_tensor.reshape(img_h, img_ch, img_w, 1)
    outputs = model(reshaped_images_tensor)
    _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
    c = predicted.squeeze()
    output_probability(predicted, processed_img, umat_img)
if ord('q')==cv2.waitKey(10):
    exit(0)
```

Answer (score 5):

I didn't quite catch your question, but you can get numpy data of an opencv's umat with "get()" like [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/fecebea2e38a97a15219219e3e1ad8cf680e9e2b/modules/python/test/test_umat.py#L36)

and you should probably [permute](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute) your tensor before feeding it into your model.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `array` instead of `UMat`, just do:

```
img_array = cv2.UMat.get(umat_img)
```

Answer (score 1):

The current answers are technically correct. Just to make it clear, just in case some of the links change, you can do this:

```
import cv2
img_array = umat_img.get()
```